# How to detect predictive text on iOS 8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8

I've noticed one of the annoying things about my UITextFields and UITextViews is I have a programatically created UIToolBar above it for a Previous, Next and Done buttons that interact with the text fields gets hidden when the predictive text appears.

I was wondering if there was a way to disable this programatically or detect it so I can move the toolbar up or down depending on whether it is showing or hidden. Or is this feature only available in Swift? I'm still using Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your toolbar the inputAccessoryView of your text fields and text views, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give it a shot when I'm next at my machine and mark this as the answer if it works :)

Comment: could you elaborate on this answer?

Comment: Do you know what the inputAcccessoryView is? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html